# How to document a function object with doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen, functor, function-object

How should I document a function object (AKA functor) with doxygen?  It feels misleading to just document it as a regular class.  I find it much better to think of a function object as a function with a closure than a callable class.

Is there a way to document a function object that fits with my preferences?

```
class Adder
{
public:
   Adder( size_t x ) :
      m_x(x)
   { }

   size_t operator () ( size_t y ) const
   {
      return m_x + y;
   }

private:
   const size_t m_x;
};
```

Comment: I realize the first question is a bit subjective.  I included it to allow for answers that just tell me I'm wrong and to just do it the normal way (with some justification I hope).  The second question is much more to the point.

Comment: This code is invalid, it should be `operator()(size_t y)` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it class documentation, put the word *functor* in the first sentence (preferably as the first word) and skip the `operator()` documentation if the meaning is obvious.

Mind you: the meaning is often **not** obvious if `operator()` is overloaded.

Comment: Are you suggesting I add `@param[in] y ...` to the class description?

Comment: @deft_code: If you need `@param`, then the meaning is apparently not obvious. I tend not to use such features, relying on descriptive parameter names instead.

Comment: Ideally, all functions are simple enough and parameters so well named that their purpose is obvious.  However, that is not always the case.  Just as sometimes I need to supply a slightly more in depth description of a function parameter I may need to elaborate on a function objects parameters.

Comment: @deft_code: then document the functor's overall purpose in the class docs and only elaborate on the arguments in `operator()` docs. It's no use describing it further with "Call the functor" or similar, since that's obvious from the name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use doxygen [member groups](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup) to group all of your functors together.  Maybe something like this would work:

```
/// @name Functors
/// @{

class Adder;

/// @}

/// Functor that adds a set value to its argument when called.
class Adder
{
public:
   Adder( size_t x ) :
       m_x(x)
   { }

   size_t operator () ( size_t y ) const
   {
      return m_x + y;
   }

private:
   const size_t m_x;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Class documentation should be sufficient. Just describe the purposes and usage and clarify anything useful. Overly verbose documentation of the obvious can be avoided.

```
/*! \brief Adder functor
 *
 *  Returns size_t sum of const member and parameter
 */
class Adder
{
public:
   //! Construct with constant value for subsequent sums
   Adder( size_t x ) :
      m_x(x)
   { }

   //! Call with value to compute with constant
   size_t operator () ( size_t y ) const
   {
      return m_x + y;
   }

private:
   const size_t m_x;
};
```